# Cannot add new user to database from java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm using the following codes to add a user to a table called USERS in my database, the connection is correct because I have tried other queries and they worked, I tried this query in Oracle itself and it worked, I'm just having problems with queries in java, mostly because of SPACE and the syntax, what is wrong with this one?

```
try
{
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    //query="INSERT INTO Users (user_id,username,password,first_name,last_name) " + " VALUES (seq_users.nextval,'"+usernameCreateField.getText()+"','"+new String(passwordCreateField.getPassword())+"','"+firstnameCreateField.getText()+"','"+lastnameCreateField.getText()+"') ";
    query="INSERT INTO Users (user_id,username,password,first_name,last_name) " +" VALUES (seq_users.nextval,'test','test','test','test') ";
    rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
}
catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.out.println("result error, " +e.getMessage());
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in closing "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post with error stacktrace, which lets others understand where and what the error is or could be. And I suggest to use `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`.

Comment: So you ran it, it didn't print any error and went through, but there is nothing inserted in the database? Can you try removing the try-catch to see if something is getting gobbled up by the try-catch?

Comment: What happens when you execute the code ? Any Exceptions thrown ? What is the message of the exception ? Have you tried printing the `query` String and see if it's syntactically correct ?

Comment: Please read about prepared statements. Your commented code is the best way to suffer from escaping problems, or SQL injection attacks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So problem is that you calling `executeQuery(query)` on your statement and this is reason why it doesn't work. `executeQuery()` method you cannot use for **DML (Data Manipulation Language)** statements like are `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. For these statements `Java` offers method named `executeUpdate()` which exists for these DML statements.

From the docs:

> executeUpdate method executes the SQL statement in this
>   PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation
>   Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL
>   statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

So only replace actual method with this and it would will work.

And sorry for my curiosity but why you aren't using parametrized `SQL` statements? You would know that not using parametrized statements there is hight danger of **SQL Injection** and many hackers using this for damage databases. You should think about it. It is very important if you want to your database will be more safer. You wouldn't believe what prove SQL Injection with database.

Only for example for you, should create query like this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id,username,password,first_name,last_name) values(?,?,?,?,?) ";
```

This `?` char is representing one parameter. Numbering starts with 1,2,3, etc.. not from zero.

And then you must replace there params with real data before you `execute` statement like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
// no set parameters
ps.setInt(1, someDTO.getId());
ps.setString(2, someDTO.getUserName());
ps.setString(3, someDTO.getPassword());
ps.setString(4, someDTO.getFirstName());
ps.setString(5, someDTO.getLastName());
ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Data was inserted successfully.");
return true;
```

So more about SQL Injection: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

**EDIT:**

I forgot to tell you when i just watching your code, when you opens `connection` and then of course you will close it, you not must call `close()` method for `statements` or `ResultSet`, all will be closed after when you close `connection`.

Hope that helps you.

Regards

Comment: rset=stmt.executeUpdate(query); didn't work, it gave me an incompatible types error, and shouldn't I close statements and resultset if I have other queries to be executed?

Comment: you can't `rset=stmt.executeUpdate(query)` because method returns `INT` either 1 like the row count or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing. so you can do it like `int count = stmt.executeUpdate(query)`. And to your second question, you should after each operation with your database close `connection` (typically in `finally` block).

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is a DML operation. Try replacing

```
rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

with

```
int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: when you close connection, statements, resultsets will be closed automatic.

Comment: if you replace "rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);" with "int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);" "rset.close()" is useless and unnecessary.

Comment: @moskito-x you're absolutely right. I just thought he'd figure it out to remove a variable that is not actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
try {    
String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=(databaseNameHere)";    

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"username","userpassword");

String sql = "INSERT INTO tableNameHere(user_id,username,password,first_name,last_name) values(?,?,?,?,?)";

ps = conn2.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, user_id);
ps.setString(2, username);
ps.setString(3, password);
ps.setString(4, first_name);
ps.setString(5, last_name);  

}
```